# How do I copy/Paste an object into another project and still have it colored

Tags: modeling, import, color

I've downloaded some tree models and they're colored, and when I copy paste them into the scene I'm working on, they're uncolored.

Comment: Use File > Link or File Append

Answer (score 2):

Use `Shift + F1` in the project you would like to copy it into. Navigate to the original .blend file, open the Objects folder, and select the objects you would like to append. Appending the objects will create new instances in your new .blend file, however, linking will preserve changes made to the original later.

Comment: **linking will preserve changes made to the original later.** what do you mean later?

Comment: He means, that linked objects will pull at every restart or so, the information from the linked blend file.
So you have an object linked, rather than appended from blend file A to blend file B.
When you now change the color of the object in blend file A, it will also affect the instance in blend file B.

Comment: Correct. So file B might be the entire scene that the object is in and file A might be the editing file for that particular object. You can go into file A which will be clean and simpler and edit it there, and then next time you open file B, you'll have the changes from file A.

(sorry I never responded, I was on my mission when that comment came through, haha.)